# Javascript Popup Window.Focus

Tags: javascript, popup

I have this function:

```
 var replyTo = null;
 var windWidth = 730;
 var windHeight = 550;
 var windTop = parseInt((screen.availHeight - windHeight) / 3);
 var windLeft = parseInt((screen.availWidth - windWidth) / 2);

 function windowPreOpen() {
     replyTo = window.open('', 'Connect With Twitter', 'width=' + windWidth + ', height=' + windHeight + ', left=' + windLeft + ', top=' + windTop + ', scrollbars, resizable');
     window.focus();
 };

 function makeReplyTo() {
     windowPreOpen();
     var user_id = "3";
     var data = $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
         data: {
             type: 'checkOauth',
             user_id: user_id
         },
         success: function (data) {
             if (data) {
                 replyTo = window.open(data, 'Connect With Twitter', 'width=' + windWidth + ', height=' + windHeight + ', left=' + windLeft + ', top=' + windTop + ', scrollbars, resizable');
                 replyTo.focus();
             } else {
                 replyTo.close()
                 replyTo = $.prettyPhoto.open('');
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

It contains a little trick to avoid the popup blocker blocking my popup window.
It opens an empty popup as first and then replace it with the right one.

The problem is I have to hide the first popup under the main window and then focus on the new one.

But when I try to use replyTo.focus(); the popup window remains hidden behind the main one, and looks like I cannot do anything to fix this issue.

Is there a way to re-focus on the popup window??

Please have a look to the code.

Thanks

Comment: It's for this sort of reason that we generally avoid using real windows/popups. I see you're using jQuery, so you should really consider just using a jQueryUI Dialog (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create one pop-up window; don’t hide it; and update its location when the XHR returns? ie something like:

```
var replyTo = null;
var windWidth = 730;
var windHeight = 550;
var windTop = parseInt((screen.availHeight - windHeight) / 3);
var windLeft = parseInt((screen.availWidth - windWidth) / 2);

function windowPreOpen() {
  replyTo = window.open('', 'Connect With Twitter', 'width=' + windWidth + ', height=' + windHeight + ', left=' + windLeft + ', top=' + windTop + ', scrollbars, resizable');
  window.focus();
};

function makeReplyTo() {
  windowPreOpen();
  var user_id = "3";
  var data = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
    data: {
      type: 'checkOauth',
      user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function (data) {
      if (data) {
        replyTo.location = data;
      } else {
        replyTo.close();
        replyTo = $.prettyPhoto.open('');
      }
    }
  });
}
```